# Is it possible to have restricted access to included class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class say `A` in A.h file and class `B: public A` in B.h file.

A.h file

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A
{
  public:
    void foo {}
};

#endif
```

B.h file

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
#include "A.h"

class B: public A
{
  ...
};

#endif
```

Is there a way to include `B` but not to have access to `A` until I include A.h?

Like this

```
#include "B.h"

main() {
  B* b = new B(); //OK
  b->foo();       //OK
  A* a = new A(); //Error
  a->foo();       //Error  
}
```

Comment: Properly no, looks like XY problem, why do you need it?

Comment: You might be able to do this with C++20 modules, I think. Though that being said having `B` publically inherit from `A` pretty strongly implies that anything that knows what a `B` is should know what an `A` is.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude looks like you misread the question. OP wants that to be an error until or unless `A.h` is included directly in main

Comment: Depending on what exactly you are trying to do, maybe split `A` into an interface and an implementation?  Then `B` derives from `A_interface`, but `A_impl` is completely separate?

Comment: "_until I include A.h_" - So, if you add `#include "A.h"` to the same program that you have at the bottom - it should compile? Hmm, that's a feature I think should have been built into the language from start. Nowadays you can perhaps run the program `include-what-you-use` on your code prior to compiling. It's not perfect but so-so.

Comment: OK, I got that it's impossible. I think that the only way is to make abstract parent class for these two classes with implementation of `foo()`

Comment: Again most probably this is XY problem, describe what you are trying to achieve and there will be better solution.

Comment: Put everything into a `namespace Frog` and then within there a `namespace detail_` in a `frog_detail.h`.  Have `B.h` do a `#include "frog_detail.h"` and just do a `using Frog::detail_::B` or even better `namespace Frog { using detail_::B; }` so as not to pollute the global namespace which is already a morass of global symbols.  The `A.h` just does a `using Frog::detail_::A` or `namespace Frog { using detail_::A; }`.  Great for big projects, overkill for small projects.

Comment: @Slava I'm trying to implement my own `map` and `set` classes. `map` is a `set` with a node having value so I wanted to derive `map` from `set`. And I want it to be impossible to access `set` if I only include `map` into main.cpp. Now I have an idea to create `BST` class with protected constructor and derive `set` and `map` from it.

Comment: It is not necessary to prohibit accessing set when it is not included. For example many types from standard library "work" when not included. You should focus on making library work when it is used properly, rather than make it brake when it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. B.h depends on the definition of A, so there is no way to include B.h without including the definition of A. And there is no way of getting around that dependency if B must be defined in B.h and if B must inherit A.

You can make the creation of separate `A` into an error by changing `A` to be an abstract type. But that would remain an error even if A.h was included separately.